# Character instance slowdown

Tags: python

I'm making a Mario clone in PyGame and I am writing a function that, after releasing the left and right button while Mario is moving horizontally, slows him down until he is at rest. As of right now, the code I am using is functional and works the way it should. Though, I am not sure if there is a way I can write the following code more efficiently:

```
self.deacc = 0.5 # Always a positive number, never changed anywhere in the code.

if self.horzDir == 'l': # if mario is moving left.
    self.x += self.dx
    self.dx += self.deacc

    # To ensure marios velocity doesnt go below zero.
    if self.dx > (self.deacc * -1): 
        self.dx = 0
else:
    self.x += self.dx
    self.dx -= self.deacc

    # Also to ensure marios velocity doesnt go below zero.
    if self.dx < self.deacc:
        self.dx = 0
```

Everything is working correctly, but I feel like it can be more efficient than this because the if and else statements are very similar, just with slightly different calculations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important difference between your `if` and your `else` is this:

```
self.dx += self.deacc
```

vs.

```
self.dx -= self.deacc
```

The rest can work just fine without being in if or else.

Also, when you copy-paste code, which you apparently did to check the bounds on `self.dx`, you should change the comments. Both of your comments say "go below zero". It was a bit hard for me to understand the purpose of your `if self.dx > (self.deacc * -1):`.

If I understand your code correctly, and if my Python syntax skills are correct, I think it should work to do it like this:

```
self.x += self.dx
self.dx += (self.deacc if self.horzDir == 'l' else -self.deacc)

if Math.abs(self.dx) < self.deacc:
    self.dx = 0
```

If I understand your code correctly, you are stopping Mario whenever his velocity (`self.dx`) gets close enough to zero. This can be accomplished by taking the absolute value of `self.dx` (which will get rid of a possible negative sign) and check if it is below `self.deacc`. If it is, Mario should stop. I think describing this as "stop Mario if his speed is too slow" is more accurate than "ensure Mario's velocity doesn't go below zero."

Comment: Yes this works just as expected. One thing I'm curious about though is the second line, is the way you wrote it the "pythonic" way? It just seems more confusing written that way.

Comment: @Robbie I honestly don't know what's Pythonic or not. I rarely write Python. That is Pythons version of the [conditional operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator), written in other languages as `a ? b : c`, but in Python it is `b if a else c`

Answer (score 1):

If `self.deacc` is a constant it probably makes sense to not have this be a instance variable. The Python convention is to name such constants in all caps. It's possible that making it a class level variable is best here.

It looks like what you are trying to do is to make it such that when the magnitude of the velocity falls below a certain threshold you stop all velocity. By thinking of the velocity as a vector this code can be made clearer.

First you can pull the changes to `self.x` out from the conditional:

```
DECELERATION_FACTOR = 0.5 

self.x += self.dx
if self.horzDir == 'l': # if mario is moving left.
    self.dx += self.DECELERATION_FACTOR

    # To ensure marios velocity doesnt go below zero.
    if self.dx > (DECELERATION_FACTOR * -1): 
        self.dx = 0
else:
    self.dx -= DECELERATION_FACTOR

    # Also to ensure marios velocity doesnt go below zero.
    if self.dx < self.DECELERATION_FACTOR:
        self.dx = 0
```

Then you can see that what we are dealing with is a delta with the velocity:

```
DECELERATION_FACTOR = 0.5 

self.x += self.dx
if self.horzDir == 'l': # if mario is moving left.
    dx_delta = DECELERATION_FACTOR
else:
    dx_delta = -DECELERATION_FACTOR

self.dx += dx_delta
#if velocity update is less than threshold just set next change to 0
if abs(self.dx) < DECELERATION_FACTOR:
    self.dx = 0
```

This has effectively removed a level of nesting for the conditionals.